# Как скачать аватарку пользователя в aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

Целью является использование аватарки пользователя в модуле pillow, если не ошибаюсь, нужно загрузить фото к себе и уже после делать действия
Как мне скачать аватарку пользователя, который написал боту?
Код:

```
from aiogram import Bot, types, Dispatcher
bot = Bot(token="token", parse_mode="HTML")

@dp.message_handler(text=["text"])
async def new_message(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("Скоро все будет готово!")
    a = await bot.get_user_profile_photos(message.from_user.id)
    print(a)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не уверен, что это правильный путь к решению Вашей задачи, однако оно работает:

```
user_profile_photo: UserProfilePhotos = await bot.get_user_profile_photos(message.from_user.id)
if len(user_profile_photo.photos[0]) > 0:
   file = await bot.get_file(user_profile_photo.photos[0][0].file_id)
   await bot.download_file(file.file_path, 'user profile photo.png')
else:
   print('У пользователя нет фото в профиле.')
```

*P.S.:* для тайп хинтинга user_profile_photo импортируйте тип `from aiogram.types import UserProfilePhotos`.

Answer (score 1):

Ссылаясь на [документацию фреймворка aiogram](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/api/methods/get_user_profile_photos.html), вам использовать метод `bot.get_user_profile_photos`:

`user_profile_photo = await bot.get_user_profile_photos(user_id)`
Важное примечание: этот метод относится к 3 версии aiogram. Но, скорее всего, в двойке абсолютно такой же метод.

Comment: так я получаю айди фото, но как скачать фото?

Comment: У меня получилось такое решение:
    `user_profile_photo: UserProfilePhotos = await bot.get_user_profile_photos(message.from_user.id)
    if len(user_profile_photo.photos[0]) > 0:
        file = await bot.get_file(user_profile_photo.photos[0][0].file_id)
        await bot.download_file(file.file_path, 'user profile photo.png')
    else:
        print('У пользователя нет фото в профиле.')`

Comment: сделайте это ответом, пожалуйста, поставлю галочку